# There is a missing currency sent to the account, please be sure to confirm it

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, blockchain, wallets

Missing Ethereum Transaction! From Poloniex to my ETH wallet
this process
Address: 0x9434903Dc1a16872EF1F80920CC71EE8d70d8Cf4
Txid: 0x1d5a31b99a16971c010e4c9fb2f16e2ee8a9540b1a18f4d3e505e304f76e49ad

Comment: What wallet are you using?

Comment: That transaction completed successfully. What Ether is missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that Ethereum transactions may sometimes be delayed based on network conditions and on the gas price specified for the transaction (The higher the gas price the faster the transaction will tend to go through.)

In this case however it looks like the transaction *did* go through!  In fact it went through more than two days before you asked this question!

The best method currently available to view a transaction is to look on [etherscan.io](http://etherscan.io).

The specific link for your transaction is:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1d5a31b99a16971c010e4c9fb2f16e2ee8a9540b1a18f4d3e505e304f76e49ad

Looking at that page we can see that 0.995 ETH was transferred from the Poloniex Wallet address to your address.  This transfer went through on December 21st, 2017, at 01:59:09 PM +UTC.

Congratulations on getting your Ether :)